# How to retrieve data from iCloud Production environment

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

Is there a way to access data from iCloud production environment through iOS simulator? Because I need to retrieve an application data to analyze them, so if I could do it from simulator it will be easier to me.
If it's not possible to access with simulator, Could you give me an idea to do it with iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to archive your app and distribute it using testflight. An app distributed with tesflight is always linked to the production database. As far as I know there is no way to connect to the production database from the simulator or while debugging.